# How do I move an OpenGL view between content views

Tags: android, layout, opengl-es, view

I have a layout that is loaded in the Activity's onCreate(). I then add an extended OpenGL view to the layout. On the activity's onConfigurationChanged() method I want to load a new layout, and move the OpenGL view into it so I don't have to re-create all of the textures/objects/etc. that is under it which takes a while. How would I go about doing this properly?